# Real Analysis: subset of R with empty interior can contain a subset which is not Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Is it true that a subset of R with empty interior can contain a subset which is not Lebesgue measurable? Can you give me a justification

Comment: It's true. Half of one way to get this result is knowing that any set of positive measure contains a nonmeasurable set. The other half is knowing that . . .

Comment: *Hint*: $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, or equivalently, $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ has empty interior.

Comment: @user10354138: Despite writing [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1886404/13130), it seems that I keep misreading what OP's *actually write*! This is not the first time I've read "closure has empty interior" when only "empty interior" was written, regardless of what the OP might have intended. I don't know what was intended here, but certainly fewer nontrivial results need to be employed to answer the question as asked than what I was thinking of.